# Android: Is it good practice to store Views as global variable in class?

Tags: android, performance

I am new to Android, and have been reading that memory management is very important in those memory limited apps.

I have read some where that activity's `findViewById()` is very expensive. So i'm wondering, if it is good practice to store the Views that you will be using as a global variable and reuse the object? Or is it better to run `findViewById()` everytime i need to use the view?

Thanks,
Kev

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If what you mean is `static variable` by `global variable`, then **never ever do that!** If you keep views as static variables, the activities holding the views will leak.

All the views that you see on the screen are attached to a certain activity, and they hold a reference to the activity, if you keep a static reference to one of the views, the activity will never be garbage collected when the activity is *killed*(either by pressing the BACK key or you call the `finish()` method on the activity).

As for `findViewById()`, I don't think you need to care much about the performance of it, it may expose some overhead, but it is only **relatively** expensive, it's fast enough for most apps.

Answer (score 5):

When you say "store a view as a global variable", I guess you mean "keeping a reference to the view as a private property in the Activity class". This should not be a problem as far as memory is concerned: keeping an additional reference to the view does not mean storing the whole object again in memory.

What you have to keep in mind is that if you keep a reference to an object, the garbage collector will not be able to clean it from memory even if it is not needed anymore. But since your view is probably not supposed to be destroyed before your activity is, keeping a reference to it in the Activity class should not lead to memory leaks.

So in short: if you need to access your view frequently in your Activity class, I would say it's good practise. At least this is what I do, so if anybody disagrees I'd be very interested to know why.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is better to make Views as member variables of your activity.(in java there are no global variables, the variables that are declared in a class are called member variables).

```
public MyActivity extends Activity{
    private View mView;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedState){
        super.onCreate(savedState);
        setContentView(layout);
        mView = findViewById(id);
    }
}
```

Comment: Such statement deserves some reasoning.. Why is it better? Is it always true?

Comment: As stated in the question itself, findViewByid is a costlier operation when you compare it with just reading a member variable. As you would be using the view's instance at multiple places, it's better to make it a member variable. (definitely not static, as it leaks the whole context)

Answer (score 0):

Storing it as a private member of your class is typical for something you will be using multiple times.  A pointer to an object like that. Is tiny.